# MemoryStream service in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am getting into a tangle creating DI services in .NET Core.
  I have created a service that uses MemoryStream to convert an image into a byte[].

1. I have working code in the controller like this:

   ```
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       await model.UserPhoto.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
       user.UserPhoto = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }
   ```
2. But I want to move it out of my controller to a 'service' layer.  I have created the following 'service', which does not work: but I can't get it to work:

   ```
   private readonly MemoryStream _stream;
   public Stream(MemoryStream stream)
   {
      _stream = stream;
   }
   public Byte[] GetPic(IFormFile f)
   {
       f.CopyToAsync(_stream);
       return _stream.ToArray();
   }
   ```

This service I call from my controller like so:

```
user.UserPhoto = _stream.GetPic(model.UserPhoto);
```

And it is registered in ConfiguredServices, like so:

```
services.AddTransient<IStream, Stream>();
```

But the new MemoryStream needs to be instantiated somewhere, I think.  Is that right, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the service to create the memory stream within the method itself within a using so that it can be disposed of properly when out of scope

```
public interface IStream {
    Task<byte[]> GetPic(IFormFile file);
}

public class StreamService : IStream {
    public async Task<byte[]> GetPic(IFormFile file) {
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And used in the action...

```
user.UserPhoto = await _stream.GetPic(model.UserPhoto);
```

Assuming it was registered

```
services.AddTransient<IStream, StreamService>();
```

and injected into the controller via constructor injection.

Comment: Thank you again @Nkosi.  That's great.  I was unsure about instantiating the MemoryStream (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) in the service itself.  But it needs to be done somwhere!